# multivariate curvefit using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit data to a specific function to build an empirical relationship.

```py
def abrasion_fit_function(x_data, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    P, Q, R, S, U, V = x_data
    return a * np.power(P, b) * np.power(Q, c) * np.power((R / S), d) * np.power(U, e) / np.power(V, f)
```

dataframe looks like this:

```py
column_names = ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U', 'V', 'L', 'M', 'Y']
values = np.concatenate(appended_data, axis=0)
df_data = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=column_names)
```

and the curvefit function is called like this:

```py
params, params_covariance = curve_fit(CustomFitFunctions().abrasion_fit_function,
                                          df_data[['P', 'Q', 'R','S', 'U', 'V']],
                                          df_data['Y'])
```

it throw me an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./abrasion_model.py", line 111, in <module>
        df_data['average-mass-change'])
      File "/Users/nipungoel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 756, in curve_fit
        res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/nipungoel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 383, in leastsq
        shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
      File "/Users/nipungoel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
        res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
      File "/Users/nipungoel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 458, in func_wrapped
        return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
      File "/Users/nipungoel/research/gen3csp/gen3csp_codes/custom_fit_functions.py", line 39, in abrasion_fit_function
        np.power(velocity, e) / np.power(hardness_ratio, f)
    TypeError: ufunc 'power' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Can anyone help? I guess that it may be because i'm trying to do a division on a dataframe column? or using a power function on dataframe column? i'm a bit lost.

Comment: check your data types: `df_data.dtypes`

Comment: all the columns are returned as objects:
P               object
Q               object
R               object
S               object
U               object
V               object
L               object
M              object
Y               object
dtype: object

Comment: look like you have strings. You really want them to be `float` or `float64`

Comment: would it be the column names? those are the only things that are strings in the dataframe that i sent to the curvefit.

Comment: Use `to_numeric` to convert the object data type variables to floats

Comment: added an update below. any more suggestions @dkritz

Answer (score 0):

i made a couple of changes. perhaps i couldn't pass a dataframe to the curve_fit function. so i converted the dataframe to an array (besides changing the dtypes to float as suggested).

```
x_data = df_data[['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U', 'V']].copy(deep=True).to_numpy()
y_data = df_data['Y'].copy(deep=True).to_numpy()


params, params_covariance = curve_fit(CustomFitFunctions().abrasion_fit_function, x_data.T, y_data)
```

Now I'm getting a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./abrasion_model.py", line 116, in <module>
    x_data = df_data[['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'U', 'V']].copy(deep=True).to_numpy()
  File "/Users/nipungoel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 756, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nipungoel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 387, in leastsq
    raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
TypeError: Improper input: N=6 must not exceed M=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. Turned out i have less than 6 equations. I failed at math. 6 variables need at least 6 or more data points to fit with.
Added 3 more points at it worked flawlessly with the changes i made in the above post.